# Retrieve 'elementname' from $('elementname')?

Tags: mootools, element

Relevent HTML:

```
<p id="baz"></p>
```

Relevent code:

```
function foo(element) {
    element.innerHTML = 'bar';
    alert(element.toString() + ' has been modified');
}

foo($('baz'));
```

[Relevent jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uC3P7/)

This alerts "[object HTMLParagraphElement] has been modified". Is there any way to have "baz has been modified"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, replace element.toString() with .get('id')

```
function foo(elementname) {
    elementname.set("html", 'bar');
    alert(elementname.get('id') + ' has been modified');
}

foo('baz');
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I think I have a case of the Mondays... on Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(elementname) {
    $(elementname).innerHTML = 'bar';
    alert(elementname + ' has been modified');
}

foo('baz');
```

Comment: Guh, you're right. My contrived examples fail. Let me rewrite my code in the original post.